# In php extract specific text from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have long string which can contain ids like `desk_123` `desk_456` `desk_678` means static text `desk_` and any numbers. I want to extract this type of id from a text please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you

```
$str = 'desk_123';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: well, if he wants to extract the *desk_* also the regexp should be /(desk_\d+)/

Comment: @mTorres yes but he wanted to only extract the ID, otherwise he would of just called the string in the first place.

Comment: Well for what I understand of the question, the srring is not ```desk_\d+``` but a ling string with the pattern in it... otherwise you are absolutely right :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$deskNumbers[] = array_map(
    function($value) {
        sscanf($value, 'desk_%d');
    },
    explode(' ', $myVeryLongString)
);
```